# Array has incomplete element type 'bool'

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, boolean, cs50

So yeah, this is the error and I'm not sure how to fix this: test.c:5:12: error: array has incomplete element type 'bool []'

This is part of a bigger code but all that's relevant is included.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int candidate_count = 3;
bool locked[][] = {locked[0][1] = false, locked[0][2] = false, locked[1][0] = false, locked[1][2] = false, locked[2][0] = false, locked[2][1] = false};


int main(void)
{
    int lockedCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++) {
            if(locked[i][j] == false) {
                locked[i][j] = true;
                printf("locked %i vs %i\n", i, j);
            }
            if(i == candidate_count - 2) {
                for(int k = 0; k < candidate_count; k++)
                    if(locked[k][j] == true) {
                        lockedCount += 1;
                        printf("locked %i vs %i\n", i, k);
                    }
                if(lockedCount == 0) {
                    printf("didn't %i vs %i\n", i, j);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    locked[i][j] = true;
                    printf("locked %i vs %i\n", i, j);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These declaration and initialization of an array

```
bool locked[][] = {locked[0][1] = false, locked[0][2] = false, locked[1][0] = false, locked[1][2] = false, locked[2][0] = false, locked[2][1] = false};
```

is incorrect at least because the element of the array type `bool[]` is an incomplete type.

You need to write for example like

```
bool locked[][3] = 
{
    { [1] = false, [2] = false },
    { [0] = false, [2] = false }, 
    { [0] = false, [1] = false }
};
```

Or alternatively like

```
bool locked[][3] = 
{
    [0] = { [1] = false, [2] = false },
    [1] = { [0] = false, [2] = false }, 
    [2] = { [0] = false, [1] = false }
};
```

In fact these declaration and initialization is equivalent to

```
bool locked[3][3] = 
{
    false
};
```

because all elements of the array in your declaration are initialized by zeroes that is the value of the macro `false`..

Or as the array has static storage duration then it is by default initialized by zeroes. So you could even write

```
bool locked[3][3];
```

And you forgot to include the header `<stdbool.h>`. It is better to include explicitly headers that are required.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool locked[][3] = 
{
    { [1] = false, [2] = false },
    { [0] = false, [2] = false }, 
    { [0] = false, [1] = false }
};

int main(void) 
{
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But could you explain it to me like I was five, what exactly "incomplete type" means in this case?

Comment: @ILoveYeezis The C compiler can't deduce the size of "multi-dimensional" array, only the first "dimension" can be omitted when declaring arrays of arrays.

Comment: @ILoveYeezis You declared a two-dimensional array. The element type of your two-dimensional array is bool[]. That is the size of an object of the type bool[] is unknown. if you will try for example to write printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( bool[] ) ); the compiler will issue a similar error.

Comment: As a global variable `locked` gets initialized with `0`s, therefore the whole initialization list is unnecessary. `bool locked[3][3];` does the same thing, all entries are `false`.

Comment: So with one dimensional array the program has no problem of not knowing the size of object?

Comment: @ILoveYeezis When you have a one-dimensional array when the element type is bool the size of which (that is the type _Bool) is known. When you have a two-dimensional array then the element type is bool[] that is a one-dimensional array of unknown size. So the compiler issues an error.

Comment: Alright, last question - in your example you declared the boolean statements for each dimension separately. How would I define that locked[1][0] is true? Like this: { [1] = true, [0] = true }? A bit confusing notation, as in I'm not sure why I'm declaring them separately if they're tied. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @ILoveYeezis All approaches are shown in my answer. You could write for example  [1] = { [0] = true }